# Changing colour of text printed into the console on java

Tags: colors, console

I have a grid with an x that moves around the grid randomly, only problem is the x is too hard to distinguish from the rest of the grid, so I wanted to try to change the colour of my X to red. is this possible, and if it is, how do i do it? this is all happening in the console by the way. I am using the Eclipse IDE and I put the ANSI code into a string and then add it to the printed line like this

```
String RED = code for red;
System.out.println(red + " X");
```

ANSI code doesn't seem to work for me so are there any other approaches?

Comment: Which IDE?. I've used ANSI and it works.  Show how you are using ANSI

Comment: The eclipse console doesn't support ANSI escape codes but there is a plugin for this.